# BinaryMessageEncoding with HTTPSTransport

Tags: .net, wcf, https

Actually I'm having problems implementing both HTTPS and [compression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53718/Extending-WCF-Part-II) on the same WCF Web Service, but the problem is easier to explain using BinaryMessageEncoding, and the cause is propably the same.

I have configured both the service and the client like this:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="OwnBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
    <binaryMessageEncoding>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999" />
    </binaryMessageEncoding>
    <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="999999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

But it keeps giving me following CommunicationException:

*An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:8036/Services/FileService. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.*

InnerException: *{"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}*

I know it suggest this is due to a invalid sertificate, and I have tried this also with [this trick](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/12/Accepting-invalid-Certificates-for-WCFWeb-ServicesHttpWebRequest-gets-easier), but it still doesn't work. (I don't have a sertificate, and really don't need one. I just need SSL encryption and compression. No need to authenticate either server or client.

ServiceTraceViewer doesn't show anything useful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **need a server certificate** in order to enable HTTPS. This is a requirement since the [Transport Level Security (TLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol uses asymmetric cryptography in order to exchange the session key with the client through a secure channel.

You can [create a temporary self-signed certificate to use during development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx) and install it in the `CurrentUser\My` store using the [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) utility:

```
makecert -n "CN=MyTestCertificate" -r -ss my
```

Then, you can easily [configure your WCF service to use that certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx#Step4) using the [<serviceCertificate>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731340.aspx) element in a custom service behavior:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureService">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=MyTestCertificate" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

If you're hosting your service in IIS, you also have to [enable SSL on the web site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/) where the service is running before you'll be able to communicate with it through HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in order to do HTTPS comminucation, you need a certificate. You dont have to buy one for testing purposes, you can make your own using [makecert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548309.aspx)

**MakeCert** (Makecert.exe) is a command-line tool that creates an X.509 certificate that is signed by a system test root key or by another specified key. The certificate binds a certificate name to the public part of the key pair. The certificate is saved to a file, a system certificate store, or both.

Please see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548309.aspx) to information on parameters.

Inorder to create the certificate try this on the cmd line.

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN= compaq-jzp37md0 " -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2050 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

See this [link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/) to find out how to assign SSL cert to your website.

P.S. The trick your mentioning is for accepting an invalid or expired certificate. It wont work, if you don't have a certificate.